# How to send large data to GoogleAppEngine using HTTP

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, http, rest

I want to send a set of data (usernames or phone numbers etc) to an app hosted on Google App Engine. Lets say I have 200 phone numbers which I want to send to my app on GAE.

1. Is it viable to send them as parameter in GET/POST?
2. Data can be sent as XML stanza, but does GAE support sending & receiving XML packets?

   Also, I have read about Blob API but I dont want to send the data as file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah post should be enough for this, there is a 32mb and 60 seconds request limit but most of the time this is enough if you just want to upload contact info. But if you will be processing it you will need to store it somewhere and pass its key to taskqueue cause I believe it's paramater size is not that big, so blobstore would be best and you won't have to worry about timing out if the user has very slow connection and big contacts to upload.

so it will be like:

```
upload_contacts_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/your-upload-handler')
# On Upload
add_new_task_process_contacts()
```

for number 2, gae supports recieving from email, xmpp and their channel api.